# Create an audio player in Brightcove

Tags: audio, brightcove, audio-player

Does anyone know how to create an audio player in Brightcove? I've done a lot of research, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Brightcove has instructions on how to do this posted here: 
http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/creating-audio-only-renditions-low-bandwidth-delivery